# what is the password to user mongodb when mongodb is installed in ubuntu?

Tags: mongodb, permissions, ubuntu

When I installed mongodb in ubuntu, user **mongodb** and group **mongodb** are created in /etc/passwd and /etc/group. But I have no idea of the password to these user and group. I have to run mongod as root user, which is not suggested. Someone suggests to change the owner of mongodb data and log files to **mongodb:mongodb**. But I have no idea how to run mongod as mongod?
Any idea?

Comment: Well, for a start you can use `passwd` to change the users password. It might also need a shell in order to login properly (use `chsh` to change that, if needs be).

Comment: I will have a try to change the password of user mongodb. I just wonder, when mongodb is installed, the user mongodb is created by default. What is the password? I am confused....

Comment: How did you install MongoDB, and how are you starting `mongod`? If you used the [official packaged install](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) for Ubuntu the mongod service should already be set to run with the correct permissions: `sudo service mongod start`. The `sudo` in this case is to start the service. The [service definition](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/debian/mongod.upstart) ensures that `mongod` runs as the mongodb user.

Comment: I already solved this problem. In my cluster, one config server and one data server in the replication share the same mongod binary. And I did not use the default settings, such as the data path. So, I did not use the **sudo service mongod start**

Answer (score 2):

**Launch Shell as User:**

If all else fails, on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running on AWS, try this...

```
me@local $ ssh -i aws.pem ubuntu@foo
ubuntu@foo $ sudo -u mongodb bash   # OR whatever shell (zsh)
mongodb@foo $ mongod --dbpath /data/db --fork
```

OF COURSE, you'll add a much larger set of flags to the command. Note also that this assumes you're authenticated as `ubuntu` on an AWS EC2 instance. The first portion of each line to the left of the `$` is the user@hostname

**Invoke Command as User:**

YMMV but this should work too...

```
mongodb@foo $ sudo -u mongodb mongod --dbpath /data/db --fork
```

Comment: refer to @Phil's comment, I had to do `sudo passwd mongodb` to change its password before I could `sudo -u mongodb bash`

Comment: @Howard Lee That may be because you're invoking `sudo` as mongodb...?

Answer (score -1):

The MongoDB user might have been created to be able to access services. Should using root username not be recommended, may I recommend that you create an admin user on your mongodb database? See how to do that in the MongoDB documentation:

[Manage Users and Roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/)

Since you are able to access the database using the root username, creating an admin account will allow you to modify the mongodb user's password.

I encountered this issue with SQL Server in the past. Modifying the service account was what was required.

Comment: I think op's question is at os level, not database level.